# Compare two arrays for a value

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays which hold some data which defines whether a user has access to this article. The article will be tagged to a client i.e. ClientA, ClientB and the User when created will be assigned a client access tag. I want to compare both the arrays and if they have atleast one I will give them access if not then they will be redirected.

The array is structured as below:

```
array(1) {
    [0] "ClientA"
}

array(3) {
    [0] "ClientA"
    [1] "ClientB"
    [2] "ClientC"
}
```

I've tried to use in_array but this has returned as false e.g.

```
//$articleClient is the array with one value and $client is the 
//array with 3 values
if (!in_array($articleClient, $client)) {
    dd('no access');
}
```

Any ideas on how I can compare the arrays to see if atleast one of the values is present?

Comment: Have a look at `array_intersect`

Comment: You cannot check two array using in_array() function. Please see in_array documentation

Comment: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) -> The needle has to be a string or an integer. It can't be an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the function `array_intersect` function  in php. Eg:

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2)

if (count($result)>=1)
{
    //give access to the user
}
```

link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_intersect()` function

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

if(sizeof($result)>0)
{
//match
}else
{
//no match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$common = array_intersect($articleClient, $client)    
if (count($common) < 1) {
            dd('no access');
        }
```